# Buying train tickets from Budapesta to Kosice, Slovakia

Tags: trains, tickets, hungary

I am interested to reach Kosice, Slovakia from Budapest by train. There are two trains making this distance in 3:30 hours, but I haven't managed to understand how I can buy the tickets.
- at one trial I found a site where the ticket had the price 9.90 euro but as to be collected at "collection points", for which I didn't find any explanation
- at the second trial (in a Check rail site) there were the same trains, tickets cost 47 euro and can only be sent by usual post.

Has anyone an idea either what are those collection points and where are they described, or why can be such a difference in price between the two sites?
Thanks, Veronica

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Hungarian Railways site](https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/EN/jegyatvetelipontok.html), these "collection points" are just ticket machines at major rail stations - including the station where the Budapest-Kosice train leaves from (Budapest-Keleti). From the English language booking page:

> When purchasing an international ticket online, you can print your
>   ticket at a ticket vending machine located at certain railway stations
>   with the collection code received at the time of purchase.
>   International tickets cannot be printed at home, or be presented on a
>   display of a device

From the information near the bottom of the [how to buy tickets](https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/EN/hogyan_vasarolhatok.html) page, it appears that upon booking online you will be issued a 10 digit numerical code, and this is the code required to collect your ticket from a machine at the station.

(A similar system of ticket collection is available where I live in the UK, and it is generally a reliable and easy to use system.)

Comment: You can see the ticket machines in Keleti [here](https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/jegyatveteli_pontok/jegyatveteli_allomasok.jsp?allomas=keleti): for international tickets,  you need the yellow ones lower on the page, there are many of them near the entrances. (I couldn't find this info in English)

Answer (score 3):

There is a long explanation of how to buy cheap tickets for journeys from Hungary on the Seat 16 website

https://www.seat61.com/websites/mav-start.htm

It is far too long and complicated to summarise here but it confirms the advice others have given you that you cannot print at home or use a device you have to pick up the tickets. It takes you through all the steps and gives pictures of the two different machines for picking up tickets, the blue domestic and the yellow international. The fact that it offers cheap tickets not apparently available elsewhere may explain why you found such different prices.